# ServiceStack: implement existing SOAP API

Tags: soap, servicestack

Say I have an existing SOAP service which I a would like to re-implement using e.g. ServiceStack.

Is that possible - or more specifically: can I e.g. take an existing SOAP specification and implement that using ServiceStack? I haven't been able to figure this out.

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

You can see more information about [ServiceStack's SOAP Support on the wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support).

In short, the SOAP Support works like the rest of ServiceStack where your models are the master authority and *projects-out*, so SOAP support is added to your existing models and not the other way round of *projecting-in* and imposing the SOAP spec onto your models.